# How to stub out property on AppDelegate using ocmock?

Tags: objective-c, ocmock

On my app delegate class I have a simple property

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) LoginAppDelegate *loginAppDelegate;
```

I then offload the app delegate like functionality for all login views here so I can keep my main app delegate class small (ish)

Then on the login app delegate I have a method to push a view controller on the main navigation controller

```
- (void)launchSomeOtherViewController {}
```

The painful part is when I'm inside a view controller that invokes this "launch" method

```
- (void)callBackAfterSomeHttpMethodLetsSay
{
    [self.appDelegate.loginAppDelegate launchSomeOtherViewController];
}
```

When I try to mock this out it appears my stub on the app delegate isn't correct

```
- (void)testCallBackWithSignupTokenInvokesLaunchCompleteSignupViewControllerWithToken
{
    id mockLoginAppDelegate = [OCMockObject mockForClass:[LoginAppDelegate class]];
    id mockAppDelegate = [OCMockObject mockForClass:[AppDelegate class]];
    [[[mockAppDelegate stub] andReturn:mockLoginAppDelegate] loginAppDelegate];
    [[mockLoginAppDelegate expect] launchSomeOtherViewController];
    [self.sut callBackAfterSomeHttpMethodLetsSay];
    [mockLoginAppDelegate verify];
}
```

The error when I run this via ocunit is the usual "expected method was not invoked"

So my question is related to the way I'm stubbing this -can I do a stub that returns the login mock as I have or do I need to reach into the getter manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're not making your `mockAppDelegate` visible to the class under test. Try adding:

```
[self.sut setAppDelegate:mockAppDelegate];
```